# jquery plguin for autocompleting sentences

Tags: jquery, plugins, autocomplete

I'm looking for a jquery plugin which does lookahead typing where the next set of words are dependent on the previous word, like a cross between http://www.grammaticalframework.org:41296/fridge/ and http://complete-ly.appspot.com/examples/booking.html.

Comment: do you have that information in a jsonfile?

Answer (score 1):

Your second example (http://complete-ly.appspot.com/examples/booking.html) seems to fulfill your requirements. **Why not use complete-ly?** ([intro page](http://complete-ly.appspot.com/))

Comment: If you're asking for one that does not work from a pre-defined list of phrases, then I expect the reason you are struggling to find one is because they frequently work from large databases of phrases, which would not make the framework very portable. You could have 'dumb' sentence completion (think of all the phrases that start with 'if' for example), but it would not be very useful.